# How to predict values of column in new Python data frame using info from the old data frame

Tags: python, machine-learning, predict

Let's assume I have two data frames df1 and df2. In df1 I have several columns such as userid, sexid, location and etc. And in df2 I have all the same columns as in df1 except for sexid which I need to fill using some prediction algorithm. 
I am just a beginner and I tried another kind of problems. So any advice or useful references which may help me to crack it are welcomed.

Comment: How are you going to predict `sexid` in `df2` if you have no idea of the characteristics of those individuals (i.e. if you have no data to feed through your model)?

Comment: Oh, I mixed something up. In my `df2` I also have all the columns as in `df1`, I just don't have `sexid` as I need to predict it. I will edit my post. Thanks for pointing at my mistake :)

Comment: looking into the sklearn package documentation is probably a good start (in your case you need a classifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sexid': list('MMFFMFFMMF'), 'x1': [0, 12, 2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 12, 12, 12], 'x2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [0, 12, 2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 12, 12, 12], 'x2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]})

X = df1[['x1', 'x2']]
y = df1['sexid']

model = LogisticRegression()

model.fit(X, y)

model.predict(df2)
```

Which returns:

```
array(['F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M'], dtype=object)
```

I would highly recommend you read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html).